# favicon checker shows that my favicon is not configured for android and windows 8 and 10 - realfavicongenerator

Tags: favicon

Colleagues, please help. I don't get why the favicon checker shows that my favicon is not configured for android and windows 8 and 10.

I added the files and below scrypt into header.php to my site: [notariusz wrocław](https://notariuszwroclaw.org)

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://notariuszwroclaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/apple-touch-icon.png"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://notariuszwroclaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/favicon-32x32.png"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://notariuszwroclaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/favicon-16x16.png"> <link rel="manifest" href="https://notariuszwroclaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/site.webmanifest"> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://notariuszwroclaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/favicon.ico"> <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest"> <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c"> <meta name="msapplication-config" content="https://notariuszwroclaw.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/browserconfig.xml"> <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Still, not working and dunno why. Do u have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

RealFavicon author speaking :)

I couldn't find any trace of favicon code in your homepage. Favicon still works because `/favicon.ico` and `/apple-touch-icon.png` and present and loaded by convention by most browsers.

You should make sure to add to your code the favicon markups created by RealFaviconGenerator.

Comment: I am also using RealFaviconGenerator and yet internet explorer is not showing the correct favicon . you can test on https://www.pokemonpets.com

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG With IE11, I see a greenish Bulbasaur, as with Chrome. Do you observe something else?